# How to insert custom created user register fields value in to tables

Tags: entities, users

I have created few custom fields using

> configuration > people > account settings > manage fields

for **user register form**. I'm able to display the custom fields in my user registration page and I created a table to save all my user registration page details. I don't know how to insert my custom fields value into my table. I have tried using `hook_user_insert` but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The values of the custom fields are stored by default in the database. Why do you want to store them in a separate table?

Comment: @Indrock, thanks for the reply. I need to know the user details who enters the details during account creation. But right now I able to view only my custom field tables in the DB which shows the value I entered during my field creation. I want to view my custom fields value entered during account creation btw after creating the custom fields I renamed the fields name and added a submit button in my custom tpl file. Please help me.